# Uploading one image - save polymorphic - in Rails 5 with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

#### My issue

I can't figure out how to create an event that **must** have one picture attached with it, the picture being polymorphic (due to the rest of the app).

#### Making an event

*(Stepwise what I want.)*

1. Fill in a form for an event.
2. Form can have an image attached.

   1. Image is there.

      1. Validation success.
      2. Event is saved to db.
   2. Image has not been selected.

      1. Validation throws out error.
      2. Event is not saved.

#### My code

Currently what I have looks like this:

**picture.rb**

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_list
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

  has_attached_file :image,
    :storage    => :s3,
    :bucket     => Figaro.env.s3_bucket,
    :s3_region  => 'eu-west-1',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id      => Figaro.env.aws_access_key_id,
      :secret_access_key  => Figaro.env.aws_secret_access_key
    }

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  ## Associaties
  has_many :pictures, -> { order(position: :asc) }, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  ## Validaties
  validates_presence_of :name, :description, :date, :pictures
  validates :name, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :date, in_future: true
end
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  authorize @event

  if @event.save
    if params[:image]
      @event.pictures.create(image: params[:image])
    end
      flash[:notice] = 'Agendapunt is toegevoegd.'
      redirect_to events_path
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = 'Agendapunt is niet toegevoegd.'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

It currently keeps on giving me a "pictures can't be blank error".

I remember having the inverse problem a while back, namely how to make sure an image must me uploaded. Now I can't figure out how to fix this bug of the image not going through somehow.

Comment: Does `event_params` contain the image params?

Comment: I found some sort of a solution by adding `optional: true` after `belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true` in the picture model. Then altering the create action such that the picture is made before the `@event.save`. Not ideal, because the `:imageable` is not really optional, and I can't have free floating pictures.